# As I am watchin a video tutorials on Data Science Ikeep getting this error

Tags: python

> TypeError: DecisionTreeClassifier.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_sample_leaf'

this is actually the code that I am using:

```
x = balance_data.values[:, 1-5]
y = balance_data.values[:, 0]

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 100)

clf_entropy = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', random_state=100, max_depth=3, min_sample_leaf=5)
clf_entropy.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

I want to try DecisionTreeRegressor.

Comment: Have you read the doc https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html ? it's `min_samples_leaf`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a "s", as per the documentation
( https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html) it's `min_samples_leaf` .

Comment: That kinf of question sould just be flagged or commented, an answer is of no value here